# (SAS) Proc HPBIN output with original variables

Tags: sas

In SAS, Proc HPBIN, OUTPUT option does not keep original variables as explained below

OUTPUT=SAS-data-set
creates an output SAS data set in single-machine mode or a database table that is saved alongside the distributed database in distributed mode. The output data set or table contains binning variables. **To avoid data duplication for large data sets, the variables in the input data set are not included in the output data set**.

--> How can I keep original variables and bin number?

Answer (score 0):

Do a 1:1 merge of the output data set with the input data set.

For example:

```
proc hpbin data=sashelp.orsales noprint out=profitbinned;
  var profit;
run;

data want;
  merge sashelp.orsales profitbinned;
  * 1:1 merge does not have a BY statement;
run;
```

If the input data has a primary, or unique key, you can specify those key variables in an `ID` statement to ensure a more robust post-binning merge:

```
proc hpbin data=sashelp.citiday noprint out=dowcmp_binned;
  var SNYDJCM;
  id date;
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as 
  select bin.date, ticker.SNYDJCM, bin.bin_SNYDJCM
  from sashelp.citiday as ticker
  join work.dowcmp_binned as bin
  on ticker.date = bin.date
  order by bin.date;
```

Comment: Tks Richard. I found ID statement help most